# How to get information in one database when row is inserted in another database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two databases. How can I write some trigger to get notification in database1 when row is insered in some table in database2. I have link from database1 to database2, but I don’t have link from two to one.

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to replicate data between databases like this is to create a materialized view in database1 for your table(s) in database2. E.g.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW db1_table
REFRESH FORCE AS
SELECT * FROM db2_table@db2;
```

[See for example this article for details](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views).

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful! After materialized view was refreshed, i should run procedure for some processing. Can I make trigger on this view, is it possible or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @StefanDjordjevic: Yes, you should be able to put a trigger on the materialized view. There are some caveats / limitations, as always with materialized views, which I don't remember.